# Android boolean timer schedule

Tags: java, android, service, timer

I need help / advice for a problem..I created a `service` and in this I need to run an action when two `integers` or two `strings` are `equals`..what is the best way?

I tried with a `timer:`

`timer.schedule(new mainTask(), mydate.equals(date));`

```
private class mainTask extends TimerTask
    { 
        public void run() 
        {

        }
    }
```

but that does not accept boolean in the `when` parameter..

What can I use to get what i want?

ps: my parameters are taken from a database

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean but if the deamon should be dependant on the strings and integers why don't you just define a method like this:

```
private boolean myDaemon(String s1, String s2, int i1, int i2) {

return ( s1.equals(s2) || ( i1 == i2));
}
```

and use this as your parameter ?

However, if you want to `schedule` the timer only if this condition applies then you have to write something like:

```
if (myDaemon(s1,s2,i1,i2)) scheduleMytimer();
```

ps the second parameter to Timer is not a condition but the DeamonFlag!